# what the sign "@" mean in Rust expression

Tags: rust, expression

I'm new in Rust and while learning the standard library I found the expression `Some(x @ 6..=10)` in a match example. What does `x @ 6..=10` mean?

Comment: Why won't [google](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.8.0/book/patterns.html#bindings) first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`something @ pattern` is a way to do the pattern matching. Normally a match branch creates variables for parts of the matched value. But `something @ pattern` creates a variable `something` and moves or copies the whole value into it.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `low ..= high` allows you to match on all numbers within the range from `low` to `high` (inclusive). The `@` in pattern match expressions allows you to bind a variable to the matched value. Here's an example to illustrate their uses:

```rust
fn log_num(maybe_num: Option<i32>) {
    match maybe_num {
        None => println!("didn't get a number"),
        Some(x @ 0..=5) => println!("got number {} between 0-5", x),
        Some(y @ 6..=10) => println!("got number {} between 6-10", y),
        Some(z) => println!("got number {} larger than 10", z),
    }
}

fn main() {
    log_num(None);
    log_num(Some(3));
    log_num(Some(7));
    log_num(Some(15));
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3a29be008b8d597786b264ac68dc91a7)

Answer (score 1):

This is a form of pattern matching, specifically [@ bindings](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#-bindings). In the form...

```
let y = Some(3);
if let Some(x @ 6..=10) = y {
    // ...
}
```

... the variable `y` needs to be a `Some(...)` to match, and the inner value will be assigned to `x` if it is within the range 6 to 10 (inclusive). In the example above, the `if`-block will not be executed, because while `y` destructures to a `Some(...)`, the inner value does not fit the pattern and therefor `x` does not bind.